# How to "bind" (store) the $index observable to my observable?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a `foreach` binding, and in my data I have an observable called `Level`. How could I store the `$index` value in my Level observable? I would need it because the array goes to a server-side script, and Icannot expect that the order will be preserved at the end.

I've been googling for a while now but haven't found any related answer yet

Comment: @manji That's all right, I know how to set the value of an observable. But where shall I put it in this case? Could you please write a few lines of a sample foreach binding?

Comment: You should only use $index for presentation,  if you need an index for logic it should be implemented on the view model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not how it should be done. You should set `Level`'s value in the loop where you populate the outer list (you should have an index there), or create a function that does that if the list comes populated.

If you insist, you can create a bindingHandler that executes an instruction, and use it at the start of the foreach binding:

```
// JS
ko.bindingHandlers.setter = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        valueAccessor();
    }
}

// HTML
<div data-bind="foreach: list">
    <span data-bind="setter: Level($index())"></span>
    ... the rest of the code ...
</div>
```

but it's not a good idea. When the observable array changes, the foreach binding will run again and `Level`'s value is not guaranteed to stay the same.

### Demo: [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YHyiKtGvMpJS0zAMN5Xg?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you, I just came up with writing a little loop for setting indexes right before posting the data. However, your "setter" binding definetely tought me another color of knockout :)